CFour beginner: @MKDECK-F, Premature end-of-file on MOL error
Getting acquainted with CFour and I am running into some issues in running a simple calculation with an ECP. My ZMAT file looks as follows:
TEST Optimization on SCN
C
S 1 RCS*
X 1 RDUM 2 A90
N 1 RCN* 3 A90 2 D180

RCS  =   1.1670998711
RCN  =   1.1670998711
RDUM =   1.00000
A90  =  90.
D180 = 180.

*ACES2(CALC = CCSD, BASIS = SPECIAL, ECP=ON)

C:cc-pVDZ
S:LANL2DZ
N:cc-pVDZ

C:NONE
S:LANL2DZ-ECP
N:NONE

My GENBAS file:
C:cc-pVDZ
cc-pVDZ

  3
    0    1    2
    3    2    1
    9    4    1

6.665000D+03 1.000000D+03 2.280000D+02 6.471000D+01 2.106000D+01
7.495000D+00 2.797000D+00 5.215000D-01 1.596000D-01

6.920000D-04 -1.460000D-04 0.000000D+00
5.329000D-03 -1.154000D-03 0.000000D+00
2.707700D-02 -5.725000D-03 0.000000D+00
1.017180D-01 -2.331200D-02 0.000000D+00
2.747400D-01 -6.395500D-02 0.000000D+00
4.485640D-01 -1.499810D-01 0.000000D+00
2.850740D-01 -1.272620D-01 0.000000D+00
1.520400D-02 5.445290D-01 0.000000D+00
-3.191000D-03 5.804960D-01 1.000000D+00

9.439000D+00 2.002000D+00 5.456000D-01 1.517000D-01

3.810900D-02 0.000000D+00
2.094800D-01 0.000000D+00
5.085570D-01 0.000000D+00
4.688420D-01 1.000000D+00

5.500000D-01

1.0000000
S:LANL2DZ
LANL2DZ

  2
    0    1
    2    2
    3    3

1.8500000 0.4035000 0.1438000

-0.5324335 0.0000000
1.2763801 0.0000000
0.0000000 1.0000000

4.9450000 0.4870000 0.1379000

-0.0608116 0.0000000
1.0132686 0.0000000
0.0000000 1.0000000

N:cc-pVDZ
cc-pVDZ

  3
    0    1    2
    3    2    1
    9    4    1

9.046000D+03 1.357000D+03 3.093000D+02 8.773000D+01 2.856000D+01
1.021000D+01 3.838000D+00 7.466000D-01 2.248000D-01

7.000000D-04 -1.530000D-04 0.000000D+00
5.389000D-03 -1.208000D-03 0.000000D+00
2.740600D-02 -5.992000D-03 0.000000D+00
1.032070D-01 -2.454400D-02 0.000000D+00
2.787230D-01 -6.745900D-02 0.000000D+00
4.485400D-01 -1.580780D-01 0.000000D+00
2.782380D-01 -1.218310D-01 0.000000D+00
1.544000D-02 5.490030D-01 0.000000D+00
-2.864000D-03 5.788150D-01 1.000000D+00

1.355000D+01 2.917000D+00 7.973000D-01 2.185000D-01

3.991900D-02 0.000000D+00
2.171690D-01 0.000000D+00
5.103190D-01 0.000000D+00
4.622140D-01 1.000000D+00

8.170000D-01

1.0000000

My ECPDATA file:
! Effective core Potentials
*
S:LANL2DZ-ECP
# LANL2DZ ECP
*
    NCORE = 10    LMAX = 2
d
  -10.0000000    1   532.6685222
  -85.3593846    2   108.1342248
  -30.4513290    2    24.5697664
  -10.3745886    2     7.3702438
   -0.9899295    2     2.3712569
s-d
    3.0000000    0   106.3176781
   10.6284036    1   100.8245833
  223.6360469    2    53.5858472
   93.6460845    2    15.3706332
   28.7609065    2     3.1778402
p-d
    5.0000000    0   101.9709185
    6.0969842    1    93.2808973
  285.4425500    2    65.1431772
  147.1448413    2    24.6347440
   53.6569778    2     7.8120535
    8.9249559    2     2.3112730
*

I am receiving the following error message:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Analysis of internal coordinates specified by Z-matrix
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *The nuclear repulsion energy is   87.961930201604645 a.u.
   *There are   2 degrees of freedom within the tot. symm. molecular subspace.
   *Z-matrix requests optimization of   2 coordinates.
   *The optimization is unconstrained and your Z-matrix is great.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 ----------------------------------------------------------------
         Coordinates used in calculation (QCOMP)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 Z-matrix   Atomic            Coordinates (in bohr)
  Symbol    Number           X              Y              Z
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
     C         6        -0.00000000     0.00000000     0.68357940
     S        16         0.00000000    -0.00000000    -1.52192018
     X         0         1.76934687    -0.66368514     0.68357940
     N         7        -0.00000000    -0.00000000     2.88907898
 ----------------------------------------------------------------

   Interatomic distance matrix (Angstroms)

                 C             S             X             N
                [ 1]        [ 2]        [ 3]        [ 4]
  C    [ 1]     0.00000
  S    [ 2]     1.16710     0.00000
  X    [ 3]     1.00000     1.53692     0.00000
  N    [ 4]     1.16710     2.33420     1.53692     0.00000
 rotcon2
   Rotational constants (in cm-1):
          0.3062929777             0.0000000000
   Rotational constants (in MHz):
       9182.4337513288             0.0000000000
 @MKDECK-F, Premature end-of-file on MOL.
 @CHECKOUT-I, Total execution time (CPU/WALL):        2.04/       0.48 seconds.

  ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR
  Job has terminated with error flag
  ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR

--executable xjoda finished with status   256 in        0.52 seconds (walltime).
  This computation required                            0.53 seconds (walltime).
```


The error 'Premature end-of-file on MOL' is most likely related to the format of your ZMAT. Try to add an empty line at the end of your ZMAT file and check whether you still receive that error.

This solved the problem - thank you. Now I'm running into a different problem with the ECP but will try to work it out myself before making a different post.

Could you write this in a "Answer" so I can give you credit for it?

The description of the input file in CFOUR is described in the following publicaiton Coupled-cluster techniques for computational chemistry:
The CFOUR program package
I suspect that the reason for the error Premature end-of-file on MOL is that the ZMAT input file provided by OP doesn't have an empty line at the end. I think the empty line here serves as indicator for the end of file, which seems to be mandatory by CFOUR, maybe that's related to reading input from a file in Fortran (but I am not sure).

CFOUR requires an empty line at the end of the ZMAT file, but this is not the case for Fortran programs like OpenMolcas, MRCC, NECI, Molpro, etc.
